# Angular2 / Google maps: map not showing when in nested component

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps-api-3, nested, angular-components

When the Google map code is placed in the Angular2 app.component (as recommended [here](https://angular-maps.com/docs/getting-started.html)), all works fine.
However, I don't need the map in the app.component, but in a shared nestable component (google-maps.component). **And here the trouble starts: the map doesn't show.**

All should be configured correctly as:

A. When the code from snippet(2) is moved to the (app.component.html)
    the map is properly displayed

B. The h1 tag text (from snippet 2 below) is
    displayed on the correct location on the rendered page, where the google-maps component selector is placed

C. In the console, the window object has .google.map
    property

... so the issue should relate to the map loading/rendering

**Q: What may make the google map show correctly when used from testable component?**

Here is a breakdown of the code used:

(1) google-maps.component.**css**

```css
sebm-google-map-container{
  height: 300px;
}
```

(2) google-maps.component.**html**

```html
<h1>GOOGLE MAPS COMPONENT START**********</h1>
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="50" [longitude]="50">
</sebm-google-map>
<h1>GOOGLE MAPS COMPONENT END**********</h1>
```

(3) google-maps.component.**ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'google-maps',
    templateUrl: './google-maps.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./google-maps.component.css'],
})
export class GoogleMapsComponent {}
```

(4) app.module.**ts**

```js
...
import { AgmCoreModule }    from 'angular2-google-maps/core';
import { GoogleMapsComponent }        from './shared/google-maps.component';
...
@NgModule({
    imports: [ AgmCoreModule.forRoot({ apiKey: '...' }),
        RouterModule.forRoot([  ...   ])     
    ],
    declarations: [ ..., AppComponent, GoogleMapsComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule  { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Un-bloody-believable: a missing '.' (dot) in the css selector

wrong:
sebm-google-map-container { ... }

correct:
.sebm-google-map-container { ... }